# Read the error report of the csc.exe

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, csc

we are running compilation from script of some sources , by calling csc.exe

Is there any way to get error information in some structured xml file ? I mean , without parsing stdouptut. Maybe there is an option in csc.exe to define compilation report (I doubt about this , since I've checked on msdn but miracles happen...) ?

What i need is exact error place File.cs(34,56) for example...
Because our script checks who "owns" the file and sends notification to the developer.

Comment: Why is parsing the output hard? It is a pretty standard output format.

Comment: I don't know , just wanted to trnsfer this work to compiler itself ... If there is no possibility , I'd be forced to parse it myself , but again it's additional place to errors...

Comment: Dont be lazy, write some regex for it :)